# Nicing processes and unresponsive computers

Tags: process, priority, nice

I've a of process running on a machine. The machines are 6-core hyperthreaded for an effective total of 12 cores and the process takes 400% of the cpu so 4 cores.

I niced the process to +19 for a priority of 39 but even then, many times, the computer becomes unresponsive due to this process.

I thought nicing would effectively make the process use only the spare cycles on the computer? Is there a way to make a process use only the spare cycles and yet have the scheduler give a certain amount of time to all the other processes so the computer doesn't become unresponsive?

Edit: The program uses only ~18% of memory so I don't think it's a swap issue. The OS is Red hat 6.5 and the processor is Xeon W3670

Comment: Is the program paging? Although the CPU scheduler will properly grant higher priority processes CPU use over lower ones, it does not do the same to the processes use of swap bandwidth.

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version? I am assuming some kind of *nix since you mention `nice` but more details would be, well, nice. That said, it does sound like a swap issue, not related to `nice` at all.

Comment: Details added  .